# ¿Cómo enviar un album de fotos a un canal de Telegram usando cURL?

Tags: json, api, curl, shell-script, telegram

Tengo que hacerles una consulta a ver si alguien me puede dar una mano. Estoy armando un script en Bash para hacer de manera automática una serie de tareas dentro de un canal que administro.

Estuve investigando ya bastante porque se muy poco al respecto. Le eché una mirada a la documentación de la API de Bots de Telegram y junto con búsquedas aisladas en Google, logré enviar mensaje de texto y foto a través de la consola hacia mi canal, usando cURL.

Ahora bien, quiero que al enviar dos o más fotos me arme un album. Acá es donde me quedé atorado. Como dije, estuve adaptando los argumentos de `curl` para que me tome el conjunto de fotos como album pero en algo estoy fallando...

Puedo enviar una foto de manera exitosa con el siguiente comando:

`curl -F photo=@<ruta_a_la_foto> -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" "https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_key>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<id_canal>"`

Y mensaje de texto de la siguiente manera:

`curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_key>/sendMessage" -d "chat_id=<id_canal>&text=texto de ejemplo"`

Para darles otra idea he intentado lo siguiente:

`curl -F media='{"photo":"@<ruta_imagen_1>","photo":"@<ruta_imagen_2>"}' -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" "https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_key>/sendMediaGroup?chat_id=<id_canal>"`

Y también esto:

`curl -F media='{"type":"photo","media":{"photo":"@<ruta_imagen_1>","photo":"@<ruta_imagen_2>"},"caption":"Hola mundo"}' -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" "https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_key>/sendMediaGroup?chat_id=<canal_id>"`

Y la consola me devuelve:

`{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: expected array of InputMedia"}`

O sea que efectivamente espera un arreglo del objeto InputMedia, que es lo que quiero lograr. Pero intuyo que está mal pasado el arreglo JSON (y ya probé de todo)...
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Tuviste éxito? Tengo la misma pregunta

Comment: @user75937 He encontrado la manera de hacerlo usando la URL de la imágen. Por alguna razón, no puedo hacerlo con imágenes que tengo alojadas en la computadora. Lo hice de la siguiente manera: 


```curl -F media='[{"type":"photo","media":"URL_IMAGEN1"},{"type":"photo","media":"URL_IMAGEN2"},{"type":"photo","media":"URL_IMAGEN3"}]' -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data" "https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_key>/sendMediaGroup?chat_id=<canal_id>"```